# Avro Files always read as GenericRecord

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I have a avro files with a specified schema.
When I am loading the Avro Files they always come out as GenericData even though I am specifying the Schema.

```
val schema = Article.Schema$
val job = new Job()
AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(job, schema)
val rootDir = "path-to-avro-files"
val articlesRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(rootDir, classOf[AvroKeyInputFormat[Article]], classOf[AvroKey[Article]], classOf[NullWritable], job.getConfiguration)
```

This code works and I get an RDD with the data contained in the avro files but unfortunately the entries of the RDD are all of type GenericData. This means whenever I want to access a field of my specific schema, I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to de.uni_mannheim.desq.converters.nyt.avroschema.Article
```

This is the code I use to extract a field from the avro file

```
val abstracts = articlesRDD.map(tuple => {
    val abstract = tuple._1.datum.getAbstract
    abstract
}
```

Also calling 'asInstanceOf' after accessing the 'datum' (in order to convert the GenericRecord to my Article) leads to the same error.

Comment: If you want `SpecifcRecord` you'll need a class that implements `ISpecificRecord` with matching properties and schema.

Comment: I have auto generated the class that implements SpecificRecord from a avro schema with the avro tools jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up following this tutorial (http://subprotocol.com/system/apache-spark-ec2-avro.html) and regenerating my AvroSchema with a newer version of the Avro-tools.
The version generated with avro-tools 1.7.x is not working with this solution while the version generated with 1.8.1 does.